# Can I determine where a signal is coming from if I have two wifi receivers

Tags: wireless-networking, sniffing

I've been rolling this around in my head for a while, and I know there are a lot of variables that can effect this, but....

If I have two wifi receivers that I set in monitor mode, that will log packets (pings for all practical purposes), tx mac IDs, packet IDs, and the signal strength, should I be able to derive the direction of the transmitter?

Ok, so dumb this up a little and pretend it's a perfect test environment, no obstructions, and everything is on the same plain. Is there a formula to compare wifi signal strengths from control points and say, "This one had this strength, and this one had that strength, we're looking for a source bearing 45 Degrees from the line between our receivers"?

Like I said, I know there are a TON of potential obstructions that can effect signal strength, so assume a perfect testing environment. I'm also thinking that since I'm not looking at signal strength as a measure of distance, they break down, as long as it's line of sight, should break down at the same pace for each receiver so comparing the two strengths against each other might be more accurate than estimating distance. That's my thought atleast.

Comment: Are you asking how to triangulate a WiFi signal?

Answer (score 4):

No, not from mere signal strength. There are many reasons this won't work.

The most obvious problem: That won't describe a unique location. For example, if the signal strength was the same at both receivers, that at best means that the source is equidistant from both devices. But that describes a line, not a point.

The second most obvious problem: Devices don't emit equally in all directions. So even if the signal strength is the same at both receivers, that doesn't actually even mean they're the same distance from the source.

Comment: If we had an ideal circumstance of the transmitter working perfectly in an omni-directional state, then it would be possible to determine the direction wouldn't it? I get that even if everything's on the same plain, this would still create two potential directions, but for the sake of my curiosity, that's perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @JohnSly Nope. Say we knew that, for example, it was twice as far from one point as the other. The [set of solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2+*+sqrt((x+%2B+1)%5E2+%2B+(y%5E2))+%3D+sqrt+((x+-+1)%5E2+%2B+y%5E2)) would cover a large circle that spanned a huge swath of arc from either sampling point.

Answer (score 0):

If the you use a highly directional antenna, then signal strength can be used to find the direction of the radio transmitter by rotating it until signal strength peaks. If you take incremental readings as you rotate 360 degrees, do this a number of times and then average the results for each increment you will probably find find a peak. This is the direction.

Move your setup or use a second antenna to do this from a second location, and you will then have two lines each extending from the point of an antenna location and extending horizontally into space. The intersection of the two lines is the probable location of the transmitter.

Note that you are relying on the directional sensitivity of the antenna, rather than the signal strength.

Comment: well my question is, instead of trying to find the location, can I use two omni-direction antennas to find the direction of the transmitter? I'm sure it works in theory, but I'd really like to see if anyone has been able to do anything on the practical side of it.

Comment: I don't think that it would work in theory for a set of fixed antennas. If you move the antennas? Probably, since then you are concerned with the change in relative strength. As David Schwartz points out, signal strength in of itself tells you little.